# Extension to detect and display the aspect ratio of the current video on YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, youtube

I need to know the current video's aspect ratio on YouTube. Is there any extension that can detect and display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- right-click on the video
- select **Stats for nerds**
- if you can't tell by resolution then use a calculator: **https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/**

[image]

[image: 6]